# LogCat for Android Device in Eclipse not showing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

repeatedly my LogCat in Eclipse seems to stuck.

reproducible when creating/modifying a filter.

switching to DDMS and selecting my device doesn't help as suggested in other answers in stackoverflow.

Only a restart of eclipse helps, but this is not usable that way.

Any hints ?

Comment: Welcome to one of the MANY oddities with Eclipse. There are a number of work arounds, but I've found that none of them work reliably. What I do from time-to-time, is just close and reopen the logcat view. Seems to work for me, but I've stated it before and its hit and miss with other people. It's just something you have to get used too.

Comment: go to Devices , choose your project (from package name),click stop process and run agin your program

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I tried your hints already without success.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a smart way for doing this,  what you need to do is to refresh your debug bridge, most of the time ddms loose conncetion hence logs are not shown. Just perform the following when this happenes next.

1. Open CMD,
2. Navigate to Android SDK, Platform Tools
3. Write ADB KILL-SERVER, enter, ADB START-SERVER
4. this will open debug bridge in new port, after doing this just open ddms and select your device

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I prepared a batchfile and added this to my external tools in eclipse. Off course when try to reproduce the failure it works ( murphis law ). Will wait for the failure and report the results.

Comment: This does not work for me. Tried several times now. [2014-02-18 17:07:14 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
[2014-02-18 17:07:14 - DeviceMonitor] Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
[2014-02-18 17:07:15 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2014-02-18 17:08:09 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
[2014-02-18 17:08:10 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

Comment: Only restart of eclipse helps. Very sad.

Comment: Hmm might be some thing wrong with sdk manager itself then, no need to restarting eclipse then as well, if this doesnt solve the issue, just open task manager and kill adb.exe from process, restart is again following above steps.